# Why G.722 has 64 kbps bit rate?

Tags: codec, voip, bitrate

I'm learning a few things about codec, and now I'm confused by G.722. There's a way to calculate codec bit rate that I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_bit_depth) on wikipedia.

It said:
bit rate = sampling rate x bit depth

G.722 has 16 kHz sampling rate and 14 bit depth. If I calculate them accurately, G.722 has 224 kbps bit rate.

16 x 14 = 224

But another [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.722) article said that G.722 has 64 kbps bit rate.

How is that possible? I've googled through this matter and got nothing.

Comment: Compression?  Your calculation shows what data rate is require to capture the audio.  The 64kbps is what it transmits at post-compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In G.722, the 64 kbps (7 kHz) audio encoder includes a transmit audio part which converts an audio signal to a uniform digital signal which is coded using 14 bits with 16 kHz sampling and a **SB-ADPCM encoder** which reduces the bit rate to 64 kbps.

[Source](http://www.vocal.com/speech_coders/g722.html)

Comment: oh, I see. Just when I thought that digital signal which is coded using 14 bits with 16 kHz sampling was already a compressed form of analog signal. Thanks

Comment: That's an _uncompressed_ digital representation of the analog signal.

Answer (score 0):

Your math would be correct if there was no compression/encoding. Since G.722 uses encoding (SB-ADPCM, see spec for details: http://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-G.722-198811-I!!PDF-E&type=items), the data rate is lower than the one of the raw pcm stream.